# List made out of Templates in C++

Tags: c++, list, templates

In the boost graph library, there are property maps used. For an example, consider [this link about properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#sec%3aadjacency-list-properties). You can add multiple properties list like:

```
typedef property<vertex_distance_t, float, 
    property<vertex_name_t, std::string> > VertexProperty;
```

My questions are:

- Is there a name for this "list of templates" concept, so I can google it?
- Are there similar advanced template structures, like arrays or trees?
- Do you have a good book or weblink explaining it?

Note: I need a solution without C++11, though C++11 would be interesting, too.

Comment: This template syntax reminds me of the template mixin style. http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/mixin-based-programming-in-c/184404445 Not sure though if it is the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of template composition is called *base class chaining*.

It specifically works nicely to

- profit from empty baseclass optimizations
- making it relatively easy to support open-ended lists of *mixins*, even on compilers that don't directly support *variadics* yet

  > **Edit** In fact, indeed this was how typelists were usually implemented before the advent of (c++0x) variadics ([Modern C++ Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315))

References:

- [Base Class Chaining and Object Size](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#chaining)

Related:

- [Parameterized Base Class](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Parameterized_Base_Class)
- [Empty Base Optimization](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Empty_Base_Optimization)

Comment: Note: in functional programming this type of list is known as *cons-list*. It's analoguous to simply-linked lists, really.

Comment: Yeah, that's the pattern underlying this. I was looking for [tag:c++] specific patterns

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is also a *typelist* and is not connected to C++11. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23304/High-Performance-Heterogeneous-Container#Typelist8)'s a nice explanation of typelists

Comment: I have to agree. I live so far in C++11 these days, that I sort equated typelists with variadics. :(

Comment: Nice. If I get the example right, we even get index access in O(1) using get_type?

Comment: Johannes, yes, it's compile-time generated